# Iterate through JSON object in angular 6

Tags: json, angular

I am new to Angular and probably this might be a silly question. I am trying to get an api response and save it into an array. My API response looks like :

```
[
    {
        "name1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "api": {
               //somedata
            },
            "t1p": {
               //somedata
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "api": {
                //somedata
                }
            },
            "t1p": {
                //somedata
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I get the response from the code

```
var data = [];

makeRequest(): void {
      this.http
        .get(this.URL1)
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
          this.data = res;
          console.log(this.data);
        }, err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Now I want to fetch the "name" value from each of the JSON object. I tried doing this:

```
var ids:string = [];

for(let result of this.data){
            ids.push(result.name);
            console.log("Added"+result.name);
          }
```

But I am not able to achieve the same. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the same.

Comment: I see both the objects are differently structured in your data list can you tell which is the correct one ?

Comment: It seems you are returning a map within an array. Do you have any influence over the data being returned from your backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it with `.map` and `Object.keys()`

```
const result = data.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0]);

console.log(result);   // ['name1', 'name2']
```

---

If you want to perform that method to your http call. You can do so by:

```
this.http
    .get(this.URL1)
    .pipe(map(res => res.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0])))
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {...});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user3759616, Hope it will also be marked as accepted answer, that would mean a lot!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++ )
{
   for(let key of this.data[i])
   {
      if(this.data[i][key].hasOwnProperty("name"))
         ids.push(this.data[i][key][name]);
   }
}
```

As your object lies inside another object with key as name.

Comment: This isn't necessarily good practice. `this.data.forEach()` would be less code, better readable and in no way give up on possibilities of what to do with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
makeRequest(): void {
      this.http
        .get(this.URL1)
        .pipe((response) => {
         response.map((re,index)=> re['name'+(index+1)]['name'])
        })
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
          this.data = res;
          console.log(this.data);
        }, err => console.log(err));
    }
```

I gave the solution by looking at your response API. Now in the subscriber, you will get the only name.